# Cauchy-Riemann equations & harmonic

Tags: harmonic-functions, holomorphic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

Let *f* be holomorphic in an open set Ω ⊂ $\mathbb{C}$. Show that if *u* = Re *f* and *v* = Im *f* then *u* and *v* satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Show further that u is harmonic.

[You may assume without proof that *u* and *v* are twice-continuously
differentiable in Ω.]

---

I cannot show that u and v satisfy the C-R equations (please help) but for the 2nd part,

> From the Cauchy–Riemann equations,
>
> $$u_{xx} = −v_{yx} = −v_{xy} = −u_{yy}$$
>
> The first equality is the CR equation $u_{x}$ = $v_{y}$, the second is
>   the symmetry of mixed partial derivatives, and the third is the CR
>   equation $-v_{x}$ = $u_{y}$. Thus the continuity of the second
>   partials is needed for $v_{xy}$ = $v_{yx}$ and hence for the proof to
>   work.

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument for the second part looks fine, but you could get rid of the last sentence. For the first part, use the limit definition $$f'(z) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(z + h) - f(z)}{h}$$ and consider $h\to 0$ along the real and imaginary axes separately. In one case, $f'(z) = u_x + iv_x$, and in the other case, $f'(z) = -i(u_y + iv_y) = v_y - iu_y$. Compare real and imaginary parts to establish the Cauchy-Riemann equations.